# Adding a data source via REST call in Dremio

Tags: java, rest, dremio

I am trying to create a new data source in Dremio using REST API.

While the docs are pretty decent, they lack real examples which is where I fail.

So wanting to add a new data source I do the following REST calls:

1. [Login to get the session token](https://docs.dremio.com/rest-api/overview.html#authentication)
2. [Create a datasource](https://docs.dremio.com/rest-api/catalog/post-catalog.html):
   So I can create a folder structure or create a virtual dataset which is based on SQL query of pre-existing data. However I am failing to add a new PHYSICAL_DATASET or promote VIRTUAL_DATASET to a physical one.

I am getting HTTP 400 with a message that the entity to promote with a given path does not exist (when I can verify it does)

Anybody with any experience using Dremio's REST should be able to shed some light.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you describe your PHYSICAL_DATASET

- format csv, parquet?
- Source NAS?

can you add an example of your code and file here

here example for csv

1. authenticate to get token
2. Call POST localhost:9047/api/v3/catalog/{id}

   {
   "entityType": "dataset",
   "path": ["REST", "data.csv"],
   "type": "PHYSICAL_DATASET",
   "format": {
   "type": "Text",
   "fieldDelimiter": ",",
   "lineDelimiter": "\n",
   "quote": """,
   "escape": """,
   "skipFirstLine": false,
   "extractHeader": true,
   "trimHeader": false,
   "autoGenerateColumnNames": true
   }

   }

to get {id} localhost:9047/api/v3/catalog/by-path/SPACE/FILE =>"id": ?
{id} should be URLencoded